# How to dynamically create forms?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the (abstracted) business issue:

At the beginning of each week, Forecasters estimate how much candy they will sell by category.

A category could be "chocolate bars" or "gummy bears".  Every week (sometimes every day), categories could be added or removed.

Forecasters look through each category and provide an estimate.

My View Model is as follows:

```
    public class estimate
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string forecasterName { get; set; }
        public int forecasterPrediction { get; set; }
        public int salesDeptPrediction { get; set; }
        public int financeDeptPrediction { get; set; }
    }
```

My database, which is in Entity Framework, is exactly the same.

Let us say the database has the following rows:

1 | Bob Forecaster  | [null] | 4500 | 4000

2 | Hank Forecaster | [null] | 4500 | 4000

3 | Ike  Forecaster | [null] | 4500 | 4000

How do I dynamically create a form that reads the number of instances in this DataBase, and writes out a form with all of the info above in a table with each "[null]" being an @Html.EditorFor item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be perfectly clear, you don't "dynamically create a form." You create a form that will be populated dynamically based on the data it's provided.

To start, you're going to need to create an EditorTemplate that matches the name of your ViewModel class in the EditorTemplate directory:

```
/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/estimate.cshtml
```

The form inside that EditorTemplate will look something like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController"))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.forecasterName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.forecasterPrediction)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.salesDeptPrediction)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.financeDeptPrediction)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

That's as bare-bones as it's going to get. Each `Html.DisplayFor()` call will simply display the value contained in the Model passed to the EditorTemplate, and the `Html.TextBoxFor()` call will generate a TextBox that, when submitted in the form, will automagically bind to the ViewModel property that was used to create it.

Now, to actually *use* this EditorTemplate, you'll need to call it from within a View that contains either the relevant ViewModel itself or another class that has the relevant ViewModel as a property.

I'll demonstrate using both a single instance of the `estimate` class and a collection of `estimate`s:

```
@model estimate

@Html.EditorFor(m => Model)
```

That View will do nothing else but display your EditorTemplate for the `estimate` class.

The following will display a form for every `estimate` that you send to the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<estimate>

@foreach(var estimate in Model)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => estimate)
}
```

Keep in mind for the above example that once you submit a form, the page will do a full postback, meaning that it will refresh before you can send any more data. There are a few alternatives to this, such as using AJAX, but I kept it simple for the sake of the answer.

Since you asked about the form itself, I'm assuming you already know how to pull the relevant data from the database and send it to a View using a Controller Action. I'm also assuming you know how to properly reference namespaces for your Views in MVC.

Comment: On my [HTTPPost] I am consistently getting NULL as part of the array.  Any clue as to why?  I am basically converting over my results from EntityFramework to a ViewModel, creating a list out of it, and then sending it over to my View - which displays properly, but when I submit, the incoming values are not received either as a List/Enumerable, ETC.   I have created an "EditorTemplates" folder with the "estimate" class in question.  And so there is a a submit button next to ever instance.